# Cannot upload images from dropbox using file uploader

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload, dropbox

I am trying to upload images using HTML input file from dropbox folder.

When I upload the image from any folder other than the dropbox the `$_FILES` array is like this

```
  'productPic' => 
array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'galaxy-ra-copy.jpg' (length=18)
  'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => string 'E:\wamp\tmp\phpF68E.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => int 0
  'size' => int 140531
```

but when uploading from dropbox the array is like this

```
'productPic' => 
array (size=5)
  'name' => string '20140729_143115.jpg' (length=19)
  'type' => string '' (length=0)
  'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'error' => int 1
  'size' => int 0
```

I don't know how to display the error that occurs! Can somebody help?

Comment: Do you have error reporting switched on?

Comment: Seems like a client related error. Can you try on another machine / OS?

Comment: I am using localhost WAMP server over windows 8 OS. @klarki yes I have.

Comment: are you sure files in dropbox folder are openable? openable for php process? it looks like php doesnt have read rights, only the rights to list filenames in the dir. Maybe you need administrator rights to open these files?

Comment: @klarki how can I check if they are openable or not?

Comment: try `$lines = file('c:\\dropbox\\example.jpg');` only $lines will contain binary data if you parse a jpg file this way, better make a test txt file and try to open this file from your dropbox dir.